# Prevent renaming of window caption and kill process by name (if exist) in C++

Tags: c++, window, sdl, kill-process, caption

I want to prevent my application's window caption to be renamed from 3rd party programs. It uses SDL to create the window and set the name.

```
SDL_WM_SetCaption("Name", "Name");
SDL_WM_SetIcon(IMG_Load("example.gif"), NULL);
SDL_EnableUNICODE(SDL_ENABLE);
SDL_EnableKeyRepeat(SDL_DEFAULT_REPEAT_DELAY, SDL_DEFAULT_REPEAT_INTERVAL);
```

I also want my application to check for a running process by name and kill it if the process exist.

Thanks for helping.

Comment: You can't. A higher privileged process will *always* be able to kill a lower privileged process, or otherwise modify it.

Comment: What Joachim said. The only thing you could do would be to frequently reset the window name to whatever you had originally. As for killing another process, I suppose you could try something like `system("taskkill /F /IM a.exe >nul 2>&1");` (*command would need to be rewritten for whatever system the program is running on*). It is worth noting that many AVs flag, quarantine, restrict, or delete programs that use the `system(...)` command, though.

Comment: Can you give me the code for "frequently reset the window name to whatever you had originally" ? The app is running on windows. Or maybe somehow store "Name", "Name" in random generated strings so the window name is different every time program starts ? As for the process kill , hmmm .. Maybe make my app auto close if process name is running ?